# Which technologies are used in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

Expression Engine is based on codeignitor framework and codeignitor is developed using core PHP but I want to know which technologies are used by expression engine like it uses angular js,ember js etc. ?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for an exchange, and you've actually mostly answered your own question, minus the jQuery. Visit https://ellislab.com/expressionengine for more information, and reference http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions to this exchange.

Comment: @jrothafer - Sounds like a perfectly suitable question for the ExpressionEngine Exchange - it leads to a factual non-opinion based answer, just because it's not related to code or usage...? See this link: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @PeterLewis Compadre; after reviewing this exchange's help topics, I've realized I mistakenly considered this question as inappropriate. I thought documentation reference answers were frowned upon (this question **is** easily answered by EllisLab documentation). Thank you for calling me out on it, and I'll be more considerate and more inviting to this exchange from now on. (**P.S.** This is not sarcasm! Sorry for being/sounding like a jerk!)

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine is a purely PHP Content Management System (CMS) framework. As you mentioned, it is currently based off of the CodeIgniter MVC framework.

As for technologies that are required to employ ExpressionEngine ...

```
-Linux or similar operating system; one capable of serving a PHP agent
-Database functionality, specifically MySQL with a MyISAM modern table engine
 -- EE 2.9+ I've been able to run in production with INNODB table engines...
-Apache 2.x
 -- Many (engineers, host partners, etc..) have been able to run EE on nginx..
```

EE depends on jQuery, a JavaScript library for front-end display. However, even the newest version (EE 2.10.1) runs on a pretty out-of-date jQuery version. There is an EE 3.0.0-beta out... but I don't know it's technologies. I've played with it and I know it has dropped CodeIgniter as it's core framework.

For frameworks like Angular etc...

EE is agnostic to those type of frameworks. EE doesn't default to using any of them. You can incorporate Angular, Ember, etc.. if you want! EE is a framework, which allows you to place other frameworks on top of it. It's your choice! It's your world.

Comment: No problem! I think I was in a bad mood when @PeterLweis called me out, but I'm still gad to help. Angular and other JS frameworks are more `server <==> client` oriented, where as  EE is a back-end CMS... it's up to you (or the client) to pick how to exchange data from EE to the browser.

Comment: Just to support this answer, EE is indeed agnostic. We've used EE successfully as a "headless" CMS - managing the data and pushing it to an AngularJs front end.